# Microsoft Bot Service - setting up greeting message

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

Today, I wanted to implement greeting message to my chatbot when users enter chat. I looked to some tutorial and saw that it seems to be easy. The chatbot works when I run on WebChat on Microsoft Azure Bot Service. Here is the screenshot picture that show what I have done. In the first picture you can see I put code in ConversationUpdate activity, and when I run build.cmd command in terminal, it shows an error which you can see on the second picture. Have in mind that I am new into Microsoft Bot Service. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you

https://prnt.sc/k7vl8h
https://prnt.sc/k7vl1l

Answer (score 0):

from your first image error message, it states that your 'Activity' is not defined. You should declare your Activity `message` and replace with `activity`.

Update your HandleSystemMessage method so it looks like the following:

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed

        IConversationUpdateActivity update = activity;
        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
        if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
        {
            foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (newMember.Id != activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    var reply = activity.CreateReply();
                    reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}!";
                    client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle add/remove from contact lists
    }
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
    {
        // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
    }
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```